# Compare two Data Base DATA with liquibase

Tags: java, database, liquibase, data-comparison

I want to find a way to compare DATA with liquibase. I tried this *liquibase.peroperties* file:

```
driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
classpath:mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar
url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Master_DB
username:sa
password:Password1
changeLogFile:db.changelog.xml
referenceUrl: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test_db
referenceUsername:sa
referencePassword:Password1
diffTypes:tables, columns, views, primaryKeys, indexes, foreignKeys, sequences, data
```

and I ran the liquibase with this command

```
liquibase diff
```

It shows me all the differences but not the exact differences in data. The result said that

```
Missing Data(s):NONE
Unexpected Data(s): NONE
```

But I know there are several differences in the data. Any suggestion?

Comment: I also tried to do some things with luquibase and mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar which only results in opening two bug reports at liquibase. So I feel that liquibase has some trouble with the latest jdbc drivers for sqlserver.

Comment: I know this tool is not developed for this purpose but when this feature is developed it's good to work well. Thanks @PowerStat, let's see what will come in bug fixes or next releases